# Laravel On delete Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-migrations

So im trying to create a self relationship where a folder can have child folders but while deleting the parent folder i get 1451 error

Following is my Laravel migration code:

```
$table->foreign('f_folder_id')->references('id')->on('folders');
```

tell me if im not doing it the right way than what approach should i use. Thanx in advance.

(also i read somewhere setting of foreign key constraint would do it but is bad idea so im looking for advise)

Answer (score 0):

You have already added a foreign key to your child table, so when you try to delete the parent row it fails because of related children on the other table.
so you have two options:

1 - to delete all the children programmatically before deleting the parent itself

2 - To let RDBMS do the children deletion on behalf of you by inforcing ondelete cascade rule.

```
$table->foreign('f_folder_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('folders')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

after this modification, migrate.

by the way option 2 is quick and easy.

Comment: What about not being able to update parent row? I have defined my migration exactly like this and i can delete just fine, but cannot edit my parent row somehow..